# python match regular expression

Tags: python, regex, match, mask

i need to compare a subject with a regex, and link the occurrences with a coincident key mask

```
key_mask = 'foo/{one}/bar/{two}/hello/{world}'

regex_mask = 'foo/(.*)/bar/(.*)/hello/(.*)'

subject = 'foo/test/bar/something/xxx'
```

the return should be:

```
{
"one": "test",
"two": "something",
"world": "xxx"
}
```

what is the best way to accomplish this result with the 3 inputs?

(this is for a simple url routing filtering like symfony http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html
)

thanks!

Comment: Do you plan to have anything strange other than `{one}` etc? for example, do you need to be able to escape the parenthesis?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what can be used in `{one}` etc? For example I think using `([^/]+)` instead of `(.*)` might be sensible if those are file names.

Comment: the {one}... of the path matches with {([\w-]+)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use named-groups, i.e. instead of a plain `(.*)` use `(?P<name>.*)` and then use the `groupdict()` method of the `Match` objects.

However, if you cannot change the inputs to your problem(because you are getting them from another library or whatever other reason, you can automatically create a named-group regex from the `key_mask` using `re.sub` and using a simple function as `repl`:

```
import re

def to_named_group(match):
    return '(?P<{}>.*)'.format(re.escape(match.group(0)[1:-1]))

def make_regex(key_mask):
    return re.compile(re.sub(r'\{[^}]+\}', to_named_group, key_mask))

def find_matches(key_mask, text):
    return make_regex(key_mask).match(text).groupdict()
```

Used as:

```
In [10]: find_matches('foo/{one}/bar/{two}/hello/{world}', 'foo/test/bar/something/hello/xxx')
Out[10]: {'one': 'test', 'two': 'something', 'world': 'xxx'}
```

---

Update based on your comment:

It's easy to pass into `to_named_group` further information on the regexes to produce.
For example you could change the code to:

```
import re
from functools import partial

def to_named_groups(match, regexes):
    group_name = re.escape(match.group(0)[1:-1])
    group_regex = regexes.get(group_name, '.*')
    return '(?P<{}>{})'.format(group_name, group_regex)

def make_regex(key_mask, regexes):
    regex = re.sub(r'\{[^}]+\}', partial(to_named_groups, regexes=regexes),
                   key_mask)
    return re.compile(regex)

def find_matches(key_mask, text, regexes=None):
    if regexes is None:
        regexes = {}
    try:
        return make_regex(key_mask, regexes).search(text).groupdict()
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

In this way you can control what should be matched by each named-group.

Comment: i can add a dict with requirements: like {'one': '\d+', 'world': '\w+'}, and if the key is not in the requirements, .* should be assumed, how can i pass this requirements dict to the to_named_group() with the match?
thank you so much

Comment: the make_regex(key_mask, regexes) is returning a str ('foo/(?P<one>.*)/bar/(?P<two>.*)/hello/(?P<world>.*)') you can not do .search() on it

Comment: @fj123x Sorry, I forgot the `re.compile` :s Now it should work.

Comment: thank you so much, but for another people who are looking for this answer, you must check if the make_regex(key_mask, regexes) returns a SRE_Match or None before of doing the search(text). (the find_matches() can return false or empty dict when have not matches
and change the partial(to_named_group, regexes=regexes) to partial(to_named_groups, regexes=regexes)

thank you Bakuriu :)

Comment: i have a problem when i compare `'hello/myname/mycity/12345678/world'` with `'hello/{city}/{phone}/world'`, returns: `{'city': 'myname/mycity', 'phone': '12345678'}`
this should return None, how can i solve this? thanks

Comment: how can i match with /{city}/ instead of only {city}? thanks!

Comment: @fj123x If you pass `regexes={'city': r'[^/]+', 'phone': r'\d+'}` it returns `None`. If I'm not mistaken you do not want to include `/` inside the matches, right? In this case you could change the `to_named_groups` function, at the line `group_regex = regexes.get(group_name, '.*')` change the `.*` to `[^/]+`. In this way the matches for the groups are limited between the separators by default. If you want to match more you can always explicitly pass a regex using the `regexes` argument.

Comment: you are right, i do not want to include / inside the matches, because should be the delimiter, i want to sanitize the regexes, and when the {'something': '\d+.*'} or another "bad pattern" is passed as regexes, this should be auto-escaped in to something like /\d+.*/, etc

Comment: @fj123x That's a hard problem. In order to do that you basically need to write a whole regular expression parser. You should either relax some constraints, or allow the user only a restricted set of elements to build the regex(i.e. instead of accepting an arbitrary regex from the user you only accept simple regex-like texts such as: `'DIGIT(ONE_OR_MORE)SPACE(ZERO_OR_MORE)WORD(ONE_OR_MORE)'` and afterwards you translate this regex-like text into a real regex. In this way you can limit the regex the user can pass and you can make sure `/` is never matched.

Comment: The format of the regex-like text can be anything you can parse, so you could even allow things like `\d+\s*\w+` etc. but in a way that you can always check whether a given regex could match a `/`. The more features you allow the harder and slower becomes this check.

Comment: i prefer to add a regex in the regexes, because is more simple in the case of you only want to match in a number range, or only when only contains X chars, etc
has no way?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing that comes to mind is to use named groups in regular expression:

```
>>> regex_mask = 'foo/(?P<one>.*)/bar/(?P<two>.*)/hello/(?P<world>.*)'
>>> subject = 'foo/test/bar/something/hello/xxx'
>>> re.match(regex_mask, subject).groupdict()
{'world': 'xxx', 'two': 'something', 'one': 'test'}
```